# SDN query brings extra records

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I see a weird problem with my SDN setup (probably). My cypher query from the Neo4j browser console returns 2 nodes -

```
MATCH (bk:Book) WHERE bk.bookTitle =~ '(?i).*robert.*' OR bk.authors =~ '(?i).*robert.*'  return bk;
```

Above is as per my expectation.

However, When I use the same query in the query annotation of one of my search method of my repository, SDN tends to fetch all the nodes that are around in the repository - 
Here's how my method in repository i/f looks -

```
    @Query("MATCH (bk:Book) WHERE bk.bookTitle =~ '(?i).*{0}.*' OR bk.authors =~ '(?i).*{0}.*'  return bk;")

...
    public Iterable<Book> searchBooksByProfileData(String keyword);
....
```

Few more details - 
1. I use SDN - 3.4.0 release version and my server is v2.1.6
2. My test case seem to make SDN fire the right query as I verified my logs.

Just wondering how can this happen - I am missing something or the REST i/f from the latest server is not interpreting the request from an old SDN client properly?

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
'(?i).*{0}.*'
```

is taken as a regular expression, where {0} is number of appearences. You need to pass in the whole regular expression in the parameter:

```
WHERE bk.bookTitle =~ {0}
```

Where {0} will have value `"(?i).*robert.*"`;